# Trying to create a macro with If-Then conditions in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Here is the code I'm using to creat a format.....

```
    libname myfmt "&FBRMrootPath./Formats";
%macro Create_Macro(DSN,Label,Start,fmtname,type);
options mprint mlogic symbolgen;
%If &type='n' %then %do;
  proc sort data=&DSN out=Out; by &Label;run;
  Data ctrl;
     set Out(rename=(&Label=label &Start=start )) end=last;
     retain fmtname &fmtname type &type;

  %If last %then %do;
      hlo='O';
      label='*ERROR';
      output;
  %End;
%End;

%Else  %do;
     proc sort data=&DSN out=Out; by &Start;run;
    Data ctrl;
     set Out(rename=(&Start=label &Label=start )) end=last;
     retain fmtname &fmtname type &type;
     output;
    %If last %then %do;
      hlo='O';
      label='*ERROR';
      output;
      %End;
%End;

proc format library=myfmt cntlin=ctrl;

%Mend Create_Macro;

%Create_Macro(SSIN.prd,prd_nm,prd_id,'prd_test','n');
/*%Create_Macro(SSIN.prd,prd_id,prd_nm,'prd_testc','c');*/
```

I'm getting following errors...Code looks good but I donno why I'm getting errors...
Any help???

Comment: Here are the errors I'm getting...ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: 
       last 
ERROR: The macro CREATE_MACRO will stop executing.%LET _SASPROGRAMFILE=;
58         
59         ;*';*";*/;quit;run;
                     ____
                     180

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

Comment: Edit your question to add the error message; don't use a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are doing, but the error message is probably because you are mixing `macro` code with `data step` code.  Trying change to this:

```
if last then do;
   hlo='O';
   label='*ERROR';
   output;
end;
```

In other words, get rid of the ampersands (which indicate macro variable references).
And also be sure to add a `run;` statement at the end of each data step and after the `PROC FORMAT` call.